# Python program to rename file names while overwriting if there already is that file

Tags: python, python-2.7, rename, file-rename

As the title says, I wanted a python program that changes the file name, but I wanted to overwrite if there already is a file with that destination name.

```
import os, sys

original = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]

os.rename(original, output)
```

But my code just shows me this error when there already is file with that destination name.

```
  os.rename<original, output>
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

What fix should I make?

Comment: Remove the file and try again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On Windows `os.rename` won't replace the destination file if it exists. You have to remove it first. You can catch the error and try again after removing the file:

```
import os

original = sys.argv[1]
output = sys.argv[2]

try:
    os.rename(original, output)
except WindowsError:
    os.remove(output)
    os.rename(original, output)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), it will overwrite on windows:

```
from shutil import move

move(src,dest)
```

Demo:

```
In [10]: ls    
Directory of C:\Users\padraic\Desktop

11/05/2015  20:20    <DIR>          .
11/05/2015  20:20    <DIR>          ..
11/05/2015  20:20                 0 bar.txt
11/05/2015  20:20                 0 foo.txt
               2 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  47,405,617,152 bytes free

In [11]: shutil.move("bar.txt","foo.txt")    
In [12]: ls 
Directory of C:\Users\padraic\Desktop    
11/05/2015  20:20    <DIR>          .
11/05/2015  20:20    <DIR>          ..
11/05/2015  20:20                 0 foo.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  47,405,613,056 bytes free
In [13]: shutil.move("foo.txt","bar.txt")
In [14]: ls
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3C67-52B9

 Directory of C:\Users\padraic\Desktop

11/05/2015  20:24    <DIR>          .
11/05/2015  20:24    <DIR>          ..
11/05/2015  20:20                 0 bar.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  47,405,568,000 bytes free
```

Comment: Thank you but does this really overwrite? It seems like it just ignores it when there is destination file..

Comment: @user42459, it replaces the destination file, if you move a file with the same name you will see

Answer (score 0):

This error only occurs on windows, as you can find in the python documentation ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename )

You should check if there is already a file or folder on the destination, with following code:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(destination)
```

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/84173/955026

If the file exists, remove it first before renaming the original file. Of course you should check if you are not removing the original file (so `script.py file1 file1` should not remove file1).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below approach which i followed and it is working fine

```
source_file_name = 'Test.xlsx'
dst_file_name = "FinalName.xlsx"
source_file_path = "presentdirectory"  #os.getcwd()
dst_file_path = "Destination_Folderpath"
shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_file_path, source_file_name), os.path.join(dst_file_path,  dst_file_name))
```

It will overwrite the existing file with new data if it already exist also.

Answer (score 0):

os.rename() does not overwrite (atleast in Windows) if the destination file exits. So first check to see if the destination file exits and if it exists, delete it.

```
import os.path
# first check if file exists
if os.path.exists(outputFilename):
    os.remove(outputFilename) # file exits, delete it
# rename the file
os.rename(originalFilename, outputFilename)
```

Another option is to use shutil.move, it overwrites the destination file (atleast in Windows).

```
import shutil
shutil.move(originalFilename, outputFilename)
```

Although it is better to check first and remove (if exists) to avoid any potential error.