# Renaming multiple files in a directory using os returning an error

Tags: python

I'm trying to renaming some files in a directory using os module but giving an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):      File "rename.py", line 32, in
>   
>         Rename()      File "rename.py", line 28, in Rename
>         os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace('.csv', '_1m.csv')))    WindowsError:
>   [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists

i'm trying to rename 8 csv file with unique name, i see that the first if statement returning the error, but when i remove other 7 elif statement this works!

any help would be appreciated!

**here is the file source file names**

```
india_2018-10-25 (1).csv
india_2018-10-25 (2).csv
india_2018-10-25 (3).csv
india_2018-10-25 (4).csv
india_2018-10-25 (5).csv
india_2018-10-25 (6).csv
india_2018-10-25 (7).csv
india_2018-10-25.csv
```

**here is the code**

```
import os

def Rename():
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    final_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, r'data')
    if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
        os.makedirs(final_directory)

    for file in os.listdir(final_directory):
        #print(file)
        if "(" not in file:
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace('.csv', '_1m.csv')))
        elif file.endswith('(1).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (1)', '_5m')))
        elif file.endswith('(2).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (2)', '_15m')))
        elif file.endswith('(3).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (3)', '_1h')))
        elif file.endswith('(4).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (4)', '_4h')))
        elif file.endswith('(5).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (5)', '_1D')))
        elif file.endswith('(6).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (6)', '_1W')))
        elif file.endswith('(7).csv'):
            os.rename((final_directory+'/'+file), (final_directory+'/'+file.replace(' (7)', '_1M')))
        else:
            pass

Rename()
```

Comment: So which one is failing? The error message gives you more information than you're sharing. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood i have added full error message!

Comment: Is the destination directory empty?

Comment: @wwii the source and the destination directory are same

Comment: What files are in the directory?

Comment: [sounds like this might solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175369/python-program-to-rename-file-names-while-overwriting-if-there-already-is-that-f/30175514)

Comment: @PeterWood i already added what files are in the directory

Comment: So, you're saying `india_2018-10-25_1m.csv` doesn't exist?

Comment: I agree with @PeterWood. As you can see from the traceback, it is a `WindowsError` where you cannot have 2 files with the same name in your folder. You might want to check if there is already a file with the name you want to replace it with.

Comment: @PeterWood yes you are right, i was trying to replace filename with _1M and _1m  the issue is case sensitive, that's why giving error! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Windows OS is not case sensitive.

When your program loops through `india_2018-10-25 (7).csv` it already renamed the file to `india_2018-10-25_1M.csv`.  When you try to save the file `india_2018-10-25.csv` as `india_2018-10-25_1m.csv`, because it already exists, `os` returns an error.

Solution: ensure your renaming conditions are *unique on a case sensitive basis.*

Also, it's best to follow DRY practice and simplify your code:

```
# define a translation table for the renaming schema
rename_dict = {
    ' (1)': '_5m',
    ' (2)': '_15m',
    ' (3)': '_1h',
    ' (4)': '_4h',
    ' (5)': '_1D',
    ' (6)': '_1W',
    ' (7)': '_1N',
}

for file in os.listdir(final_directory):
        fullpath = os.path.join(final_directory,file)
        #print(file)
        if "(" not in file:
            os.rename(fullpath, os.path.join(final_directory, file.replace('.csv', '_1m.csv')))
        else
            cond = os.path.splitext(file)[0][-4]
            file.replace(cond, rename_dict.get(cond))
            os.rename(fullpath, os.path.join(final_directory, file)
```

Comment: Did not know that case sensitive matter, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I also added a suggestion on optimizing your code a little so your conditions are not so congested.  Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to rename file to a name which is already there in the folder. 
make sure you are looking 1st on the `india_2018-10-25.csv` and not on `india_2018-10-25 (7).csv`. 
Find a way to figure what is the original cav name

```
fileList = os.listdir(path)
orgName = fileList[0].split(' (')[0]
if not orgName.endswith('.csv'):
    orgName += '.csv'
for i in range(1, 8):
    newName = orgName.replace('.csv', ' {%s}.csv'%i)
    if CheckFilaName(newName):  # check if exist and replace
        break
```