# How to get a png file in a directory and rename it to a specific name python

Tags: python, operating-system

have only a single file in  dir with a png extension :  htp_nyaguwbf_1568431.png

how to fetch the file using python and not inputting file name. But by getting the file name using extension .png and change its name to  test.png

this code will fetch the file and store it in file variable.

```
import glob, os

for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    print(file)
```

how to change the name of the file

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: So you want us to search for you a command to rename a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can rename each file with numbers `1` to the amount of files:

```
import glob, os

for n,file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.png")):
    os.rename(file, f'file{n+1}.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os

filename = glob.glob('*.png')[0]
os.rename(filename, 'test.png')
```

Comment: Ok, but it will fail if no such file exists.

Comment: @Captain'Flam - Doing research is good. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30175514/447901

Comment: Sorry @lit, I don't understand what you mean. But what I meant, is that if there is no file matching "*.png", glog.glob will return an empty list and accessing to its first element will fail.

Comment: glob() returns a list, not a string. The list may be empty. The code must iterate over the list as shown by Ann Zen's answer that you selected as correct.