# How can I overwrite a file by changing name?

Tags: python, file, operating-system, subprocess, txt

I have `something.txt` and `nothing.txt`. How can I change the name of `nothing.txt` to `something.txt` and at the same time remove the old `something.txt`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491222/how-to-rename-a-file-using-python

Comment: Yes, but then I get this error: `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'nothing.txt' -> 'something.txt'`. @АлексейР

Comment: use `os.replace()`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858026/15035314

Comment: check if file is closed or not

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61541907/7734112

Regarding the PermissionError -> make sure the txt file that you are trying to modify is not in use i.e exit/close the txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file exist. And if it does, remove it first.

```
from os import path, rename, remove


def mv(source, destination, overwrite=True):
    if path.isfile(destination):
        if overwrite:
            remove(destination)
        else:
            raise IOError("Destination file already exist")
    rename(source, destination)
```

Comment: This is a really good approach .

Comment: Would not pathlib be easier?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel I am pretty sure `pathlib` does better then what I wrote. But is it easier? Not sure. You just add another module. Especially if OP wants to use it just for this example. In my opinion it's not worth it.

Comment: Given that they are both standard libraries and `pathlib` was introduced to remove the boiler plates of `os`, I will say using Pathlib when dealing with folders and file is way to go. A one linear `Path('nothing.txt').rename('something.txt')` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pathlib` is easier. It is just `.rename`

```py
from pathlib import Path

Path('nothing.txt').rename('something.txt')
```

#### Demo Script

```py
from pathlib import Path

# create file and populate with text for demo
with Path('something.txt').open('w') as f:
    f.write('something old!')

# check contents
print(Path('something.txt').open('r').readline())


nothing =  Path('nothing.txt')
with nothing.open('w') as f:
    f.write('something new!')
    
# rename replaces the old something with new
nothing.rename('something.txt')

# check results
print(Path('something.txt').open('r').readline())
```